# Get object data type value with array of string java

Tags: java, object, for-loop

I want to iterate over an array list. I do also want to change the `value` each iteration of the list. For example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i+1, list.value[i]);
    }
```

My array for `value` looks like this:

`String [] value = {"identifier", "hyperlink", "children", "afterItemList", "beforeItemList"};`

List declaration:

```
public class ItemAndAttributeObject {
String hyperlink;
String identifier;
String title;
String parentUniqueUrl;
String functionType;
ArrayList<String> children;
ArrayList<String> attributeList;
ArrayList<String> afterItemList;
ArrayList<String> beforeItemList;
public ItemAndAttributeObject(String title, String identifier, String hyperlink, String parentUniqueUrl, String functionType, ArrayList<String> children, ArrayList<String> attributeList, ArrayList<String> afterItemList, ArrayList<String> beforeItemList) {
    this.hyperlink = hyperlink;
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.title = title;
    this.children = children;
    this.functionType = functionType;
    this.parentUniqueUrl = parentUniqueUrl;
    this.attributeList = attributeList;
    this.afterItemList = afterItemList;
    this.beforeItemList = beforeItemList;
}
```

I WANT TO:

Print out like this:

```
//FIRST ITTERATION
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i+1, list.identifier);
}

//SECOND ITTERATION
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i+1, list.hyperlink);
}

//THIRD ITTERATION
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i+1, list.children);
}

//FOURTH ITTERATION
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i+1, list.afterItemList);
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: What is the expected result you wish to have?

Comment: This is quite unclear.

Comment: `list.value[0] = "new value"` ? Please see [ask] and [edit]  your question to be a bit more clear about what you want.

Comment: Do you want to print the value of members of `list` called `identifier`, `hyperlink`, etc.?

Comment: @Bart The expected result is to print out first value for "identifier", first value for "hyperlink" and for all the other values in my array. I want to print out the first value from all the datamembers from my object called "list".

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes! The first value of all those members

Comment: Well, if that's the case, can you please share *what* `list` actually is? I mean the class declaration

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Updated my post with class decleration

Comment: But you still didn't tells us what you want to do with those values. What you want is Reflection but this is a bad idea. You can start by using a `switch` statement.

Comment: @AxelH Updated again with what i want each itteration to look like. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It is much clearer what i want to do now! Thanks for your time

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(list.value[i]);
    value[i] = "new";
}
```

try this